# Show ajaxloader on the time of $.getJson call

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i want to show ajaxloader icon on the time of executing $.getJSON.
it should disappear after $.getJSON completes.

```
$.getJSON("url",
    function(data){ 
      ........
      ........
      });
```

Comment: Use `$.mobile.loading('show')` and `$.mobile.loading('hide)` these are JQM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
$("#someAnimatedGif").show();
$.getJSON("url", function (data) {
    $("#someAnimatedGif").hide();
});
```

The animated gif will initially be hidden, and you can use JQuery to hide/show it.

The key is to show it right before you execute the Ajax call, and hide it again when the callback returns.